# Android, background для кнопки

Tags: android-sdk, android

Здравствуйте, вчера столкнулся с проблемой, что нужно изменить цвет для кнопки. Мне подсказали скопировать стандартный backgroud в проект и изменить в нем цвет. Теперь вопрос: а где он находится, этот стандартный background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В ресурсы помещаете необходимый цвет:

```
<color name="button_background">color_hex</color>
```

в макете для кнопки выставляете background:

```
android:background="@color/button_background"
```

Comment: Тогда анимация пропадает!

Comment: Правильно. Анимацию кнопки можно добавлять через background, например через селекторы или AnimationDrawable. Вам нужно тогда работать через стили

Comment: Ну так поэтому я и ищу background, как менять цвет я и так знаю :D.